# Dos Modelos en una vista MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Tengo dos Modelos:

```
public class Solicitudes
{
    public int SolicitudesID { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaEmision { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaFin { get; set; }
    public string Observacion { get; set; }
    public int UsuariosID { get; set; }
    public int TipoSolicitudesID { get; set; }
    public int CondicionesID { get; set; }
}

public class Condiciones
{
    [Key]
    public int CondicionesID { get; set; }
    public string NombreCondiciones { get; set; }
    public int EstadoCondiciones { get; set; }

}
```

Si me pueden ayudar a decir como hago para que aparezcan en una vista. la clase Solicitudes como campos independientes y Condiciones dentro de un radiobutonfor por medio de un foreach. Al final todos los campos se deben de registar en una tabla. 
Y como recibiria el controller?

```
//POST
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Solicitudes solicitud)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View(solicitud);
    }
```

Estoy aprendiendo asp.net mvc, por favor de su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

No es posible tener más de un modelo en una vista, pero lo que puedes hacer, es crear un modelo que contenga esos dos modelos:

```
namespace NombreDeTuProyyecto.Models
{
    public class Modelos
    {
        public List<Solicitudes> { get; set; }
        public List<Condiciones> { get; set; }
    }
}
```

En la vista debes hacer referencia al modelo con el que vas a trabajar:

```
@model NombreDeTuProyyecto.Models.Modelos
//Iteración del modelo suponiendo que deseas llenar una tabla:

<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Solicitudes)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SolicitudesID)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

En el Controller, de igual forma, podrás recibir el modelo con el que estás trabajando:

```
public ActionResult AlgunaAccion(Modelos modelos)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Acciones y operaciones a realizar
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: En la vista va aver varios textbox con los datos del modelo Solicitudes y en un radioButton quiero poner las Condiciones por medio de un foreach, como seria este caso?

Comment: @LuisVega justo eso acabo de poner, poner las dos clases en un solo modelo para mostrarlo en la vista ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crearte una ViewModel y referenciarla al model de la vista:

> Una viewModel es responsable de implementar el comportamiento de la
>   vista para responder a las acciones del usuario y de exponer los datos
>   del modelo de forma tal que sea fácil usar las cargas de datos en la vista.

```
public class tuViewModel
{
    public Solicitudes solicitudes;
    public Condiciones condiciones;
}
```

En tu controlador cargar el mismo viewModel

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(tuViewModel objViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View(objViewModel);
    }
```

Y en la vista la referencia de objeto

```
@model esquemaDelViewModel.tuViewModel
```

Como vas iniciando te recomiendo [Aprender MVC.Net](http://maninformatic.blogspot.mx/2013/10/aprender-mvcmodelo-vista-controlador.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la informacion, El ViewModel lo creo dentro de la carpeta Models ? o una carpeta aparte?

Comment: Yo te recomiendo crear una carpeta parte de los modelos, para no combinarlos